# spectre css meters bug

Tags: css, spectre

with last browser update eg google chrome 94 version the spectre css meters aren't working anymore. Someone have idea to fix this bug?

thanks in advance.
CC

https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/experimentals/meters.html

Comment: Whatever that is: if you are facing a bug with any software, please open a bug ticket at the maintainers

Comment: The code to reproduce the issue should be in the question itself. If/when they fix it on their end it won't demonstrate the problem anymore.

Comment: your comment doesn't help in anything. i couldn't post the code because i have low rate in this forum... you understand?

Comment: Then please share all other kinds of details that could help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

```
.meter {
appearance: meter;
}
```